# Configuring the PATH variable in VS Code

Tags: python, terminal, path, visual-studio-code

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Code 1.30.2 on macOS Mojave 10.14.3. In the settings of VS Code, I have required it to use the external `Terminal.app` application on macOS. I also have an Anaconda distribution of Python installed.

Note that the PATH variable here reads:

```
~ » $PATH
bash: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/anaconda3/bin:/anaconda3/condabin: No such file or directory
```

[image: VS Code]

The order above is different from what I get if I fire up the regular Terminal app and get the PATH.

```
~ » $PATH
-bash: /anaconda3/bin:/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin: No such file or directory
```

[image: Terminal.app]

What this effectively does is switch the versions of Python when I type in `python` in the two cases. In the regular terminal, I get Python 3 right away, whereas in VS Code, I am faced with Python 2.

How do I change the PATH in VS Code so that whenever I type the words `python`, I am always given Python 3 instead of 2?

---

**P.S.** Please note that while editing Python code in VS Code, I can always select which interpreter I want to use, but that does not change the situation with the terminal underneath.

Comment: Why don't you pick `python` in vscode instead of launching it through a shell?  You can specify its path in the configuration.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I don't understand what you mean. For me, it is convenient to execute the code I write in vscode right there in a shell inside the app instead of launching the terminal app separately and running the code externally.

Comment: In a similar case, when I had python2 and python3, I renamed the "python.exe" of python2 to "python2.exe" so that no conflicts ocurred in terminal or any other program. It works fine in vscode as well. When I type python, I get python3 and on typing python2, i get python2. Maybe this can resolve your issue.

Comment: @sk_353 Thanks for the suggestion. However, I think that won't work in my situation. The thing is when I type `python` in vscode, it first looks in the `/usr/bin/` directory which contains a distribution of Python 2 that is used by macOS internally; whereas when I type `python` in the external terminal app, it first looks for python in `/Anaconda3/bin/` which contains a distribution of python 3. The order of where to look is defined in a variable called PATH. Somehow vscode uses a different PATH and messes up the order. I want to know where its definition is located, so that I can fix it.

Comment: @sk_353 Renaming the system distribution of python in `/usr/bin/` could mess things up with macOS.

Comment: Just to clarify, `echo $PATH` in your terminal app show `/Anaconda3/bin/` at the start of  `PATH`, whereas `echo $PATH` in the integrated terminal begins with `/usr/bin`, correct? And you want to use the `/Anaconda3/bin/` Python when you're in VS Code.

Comment: @ChrisLarson Exactly.

Comment: In your VS Code preferences, can you check to see what the `python.pythonPath` is set to for both User and Workspace?

Comment: @ChrisLarson Both has it set to /anaconda3/bin/python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I have a workaround solution.

I just add one line 
`export PATH="/Users/username/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"` into .bash_profile or .zshrc

The orifinal $PATH in vscode is 
`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/username/anaconda3/bin:/Users/username/anaconda3/condabin`

And then my $PATH in vscode become `/Users/username/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/username/anaconda3/bin:/Users/username/anaconda3/condabin`

Please give it a try. I wish the workaround might help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Workspace setting `python.pythonPath` is set explicitly to the `/usr/bin`. Set that to match your preferred $PATH and you should be good to go.

Go to `Preferences` in VS Code, search for `python.pythonPath`, switch to `Workspace`, and set as desired.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this solution immediately after commenting. However, it still does not fix the problem.

Comment: Hunh. And you haven't created any .venv or other virtual environments? Maybe with `conda`? Can you check your Preferences for `python.venvPath`? How about `python.envFile`? Is there a `.env` in your Workspace folder? (`${workspaceFolder}/.env`) Have you tried searching your Preferences explicitly for `/usr/bin` in both User and Workspace?

Comment: There are no other conda environments. The `python.venvPath` setting is empty. I am not sure what a Workspace folder is.

Comment: Just a thought, but did you try this above answer, then exit VS Code and restart it? It may be (is likely) that the terminal is not sourcing the setting upon change.

Comment: No, it does not help restarting. The PATH is still the same.

Comment: This will not solve the problem of the shell .zshrc or .bashrc running differently in VSCode.  I think the `conda init`-generated files are getting confused.